# OverflowError as I try to use the value-iteration algorithm with mdptoolbox

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, markov-chains, stochastic, mdptoolbox

I set up a simple MDP for a board that has 4 possible states and 4 possible actions. The board and reward setup looks as follows:

[image]

Here `S4` is the goal state and `S2` is the absorbing state. I have defined the transition probability matrices and reward matrice in the code that I wrote to get the optimal value function for this MDP. But as I run the code, I get an error that says: `OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer`. I could not understand the reason for this.

```
import mdptoolbox
import numpy as np

transitions = np.array([
    # action 1 (Right)
    [
        [0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.1],
        [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1],
        [0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5],
        [0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.7]
    ],
    # action 2 (Down)
    [
        [0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1],
        [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1],
        [0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1],
        [0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.7]
    ],
    # action 3 (Left)
    [
        [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1],
        [0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2],
        [0.5, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1],
        [0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.7]
    ],
    # action 4 (Top)
    [
        [0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1],
        [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1],
        [0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1],
        [0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.7]
    ]
])

rewards = np.array([
    [-1, -100, -1, 1],
    [-1, -100, -1, 1],
    [-1, -100, -1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1]
])


vi = mdptoolbox.mdp.ValueIteration(transitions, rewards, discount=0.5)
vi.setVerbose()
vi.run()

print("Value function:")
print(vi.V)


print("Policy function")
print(vi.policy)
```

If I change the value of `discount` to `1` from `0.5`, it works fine. What could be the reason for the value iteration not working with discount value `0.5` or any other decimal values?

*Update: It looks like there is some issue with my reward matrix. I have not able to write it as I intended it to be. Because if  I change some values in the reward matrix, the error disappears.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it came out that the reward matrix I had defined was incorrect. According to the reward matrix as defined in the picture above, it should be of type `(S,A)` as given in the [documentation](https://pymdptoolbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mdp.html#mdptoolbox.mdp.MDP), where each row corresponds to a state starting from `S1` until `S4` and each column corresponds to action starting from `A1` until `A4`. The new reward matrice looks as follows:

```
#(S,A)
rewards = np.array([
    [-1, -1, -1, -1],
    [-100, -100, -100, -100],
    [-1, -1, -1, -1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1]
])
```

It works fine with this. But I am still not sure, what was happening inside that led to the overflow error.